# Where to upload fonts and PIE.htc for use in a custom Magento theme?

Tags: magento, themes

I am creating my first custom Magento theme and in my mockup I am using a couple of non-standard
fonts. Where do I upload these the /fonts folder that contains these fonts? Also, where do I 
upload PIE.htc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to put all fonts and PIE.htc under,

```
skin/frontend/default/[Your Theme]/
```

Comment: How to use PIE.htc for the Magento CMS page.I have a css class like                                         .banners-top .banners-top-link 
 {
 behavior: url(PIE.htc);
 }  I am using this class in a cms page then where should I place this .htc file .Please Help Me.